# Create ordered hash function by timestamp

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, math, hash

I'd like to **create a hash function that given a timestamp it will return an integer hash to use as "ordered index"**

```
statement: x > y = f(x) > f(y) // x, y are primitive long timestamps (e.g. 1612181315000)

// f(x) or f(y) is aimed to be used in the frontend as "ordered index"
```

I plan to return this new "ordered index" instead of the real timestamp to the front-end, This will allow me to order the results "by time" on frontend consumers not returning the real timestamp for privacy reasons.

**However, some real timestamps (tagged as VISIBLE) will be returned to the frontend. for that reason, a linear function cannot be used given the fact that this static offset could be calculated for the timestamps that are NOT visible.**

**Some constraints:**

- The solution needs to be performed for each timestamp (We cannot group the timestamps beforehand)
- I think that a linear function is not possible because as sometimes we are passing also the real timestamp, the offset could be easily calculated having the timestamp and the f(timestamp) in the frontend.

Please could you point me out to a feasible algorithm/solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"x, y are timestamps"* Do you mean they are [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) objects, i.e. stores time to the nanosecond?

Comment: *"x > y = f(x) > f(y)"* That's impossible. A hash function generates a hash code, and a 32-bit hash code cannot represent all distinct values for all inputs, which means that some distinct inputs may generate the same hash code, i.e. `x > y = f(x) >= f(y)` might be doable.

Comment: @Andreas They are primitive long timestamps to millis.

Comment: What date range do you need to support? E.g. if `f(x) = x / 10000`, then you will get the same hash code for values in 10 second blocks, and support a date range of `1289-06-28` to `2650-07-05`.

Comment: If you just want use the return value as ordered index, maybe a Linear function is OK? like f(x)= ax+b (a>0)

Comment: I'd like to accept the same hash codes for <1 s, and this date range "from: 1289-06-28 to: 2650-07-05" is acceptable.
Thank you !

Comment: You only get year 1289 - 2650 date range with a 10 second block. If you change to `f(x) = x / 1000` to get a 1 second block for equal hash codes, the supported date range is reduced to `1901-12-14` to `2038-01-18`. --- That is why we'll see another "Y2K" bug in 2038, because there is still code out there that stores time as seconds since epoch in a 32-bit value.

Comment: Depending on your use case, a linear function with a static offset like @haoyuwang said, or, if it's something you can split off into different groups; you can define random offsets per group.

Comment: I've just added some constraints to the problem doing the linear function not feasible, sorry for not adding before. thank you

Comment: Would it be possible to put a sequence number in the data to be hashed, then use a subset of the bits of the hash values to store that sequence number?  Additional work might be necessary to ensure the remaining "hash" bits are still a well behaved hash function.

Comment: I think given your constraints the only feasible goal is to achieve some approximate k-anonymity, like rounding the timestamps to hours, days, or weeks. The filters also have to be rounded, otherwise, a user could exploit the filtering mechanism to determine each transaction's timestamp with arbitrary precision by filtering for smaller and smaller intervals. There is no general solution, ordering and anonymity don't go well together.

Comment: A few years ago we researched if we could add some server-side search functionality to an end-to-end encrypted file storage solution. That problem is similar to yours, doing meaningful computation without knowing the actual data you are working on. The only "real" solution that I know of is using homomorphic cryptography, but AFAIK it's still unfeasible as of today. EDIT: in your case, not even homomorphic cryptography would work, as knowing the ordered list itself is the problem, that leaks information.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of rounding, could each record be assigned a timestamp which is assigned randomly from (greatest preceding timestamp) to (actual current timestamp)?  Or perhaps, simply assigned a visible sequence number?  Does the hash value need to be what is used to order the records on the client?

Comment: I think what you are searching for is not a hash function, but encryption. I found some literature about it, which raises some of the same concerns that we had here. http://cryptowiki.net/index.php?title=Order-preserving_encryption

Comment: Thanks for your responses, @ThomasBitonti your solution "...assigned randomly from (greatest preceding timestamp) to (actual current timestamp)" almost fits good but unfortunately if we are passing this random numbers to the front-end and it's being calculated from two close numbers (e.g.1612454645000 and 1612454646000) the final user won't know exactly the private number but could infer the real timestamp number because this random number could be for instance 1612454645600.

Comment: Hi; yes, this is a problem.  Note that this sort of information can be inferred (to a limited degree) by the ordering itself.  Any knowledge of the proximity of events can be used together with the ordering information to infer approximately when an event occurred.  If the range is wide enough, perhaps generating a random number in a fixed range that matches the actual frequency of new time stamps would work.

Comment: As a test case, what should happen if there is a burst of events at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to order the entries server side, and send a "temporal index" to the frontend. Strictly speaking this algorithm is not a hash function, as the output depends on all the input entries, not just one, but that should be fine in your usecase. This is the best and easiest solution from a privacy standpoint. Any other function will leak more info than needed. All monotonic functions can be inverted using binary search, thus they do not really satisfy the requirements of a hash function, at least in a cryptographic sense.

Comment: I cannot order the entries in server-side because I have different backends. some backends are pushing the information to the frontend as a Push notification. meaning that the mechanism needed should act isolated by each registry.

Answer (score 1):

Just for those who are curious: I baked a random monotonic function for *non-cryptographic purposes*, just so that we can get a glimpse of what I would expect the plot of such a function would look like. I still do not recommend using it for OP's ordering task, but it made me think that the requirements might make sense after all.

- The monotonic function used should be secret (I mean it should be a keyed cryptographic function, with the key hidden and protected on the server)
- The server must be carefully written not to provide an oracle that translates timestamps to "hashes". Such an oracle would make it possible to obtain the timestamps from the hashes.

```js
const N = 1000000n;
const SEED = 0x2545F4914F6CDD1Dn;
const RES = 200;

function main() {
    let ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    for (let xs = 0; xs < RES; xs++) {
        let x = BigInt(xs / RES * Number(N));
        let y = monorand(x);
        ctx.lineTo(Number(x) * RES / Number(N), Number(y) * RES / Number(N));
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}

function monorand(x) {
    return _monorand(x, 0n, N, 0n, N, SEED);
}

function _monorand(x, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, seed) {
  if (xmax - xmin <= 1n || ymax - ymin <= 1n) {
      return ymin;
  }
  let xpivot = _between(seed, xmin, xmax);
  seed = _xorshift_like(seed);
  let ypivot = _between(seed, ymin, ymax);
  seed = _xorshift_like(seed);

  if (x < xpivot) {
    seed ^= 0x545F4914F6CDD1D2n;
    return _monorand(x, xmin, xpivot, ymin, ypivot, seed);
  } else {
    return _monorand(x, xpivot, xmax, ypivot, ymax, seed);
  }
}

function _between(seed, xmin, xmax) {
    return (seed % (xmax - xmin - 1n)) + (xmin + 1n);
}

function _xorshift_like(x) {
  x ^= x >> 12n;
    x ^= x << 25n;
    x ^= x >> 27n;
  return x & 0xffffffffffffffffn;
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200 id=mycanvas></canvas>
```